# Linking of field data to field name between two tables

Tags: sql

I have one table name `Class_sub` where I have subjects name according to the classes, I have `weekly_test` table where the same subject's marks have to be entered.

My problem is to show subject name as field name in `weekly_test` table reference to `class_sub` table data fields.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please include some data and ideally table structure in your question.  If you ask the community to volunteer their time helping you, you should be prepared to invest at least 5-10 minutes writing your question.

Comment: put example of how tables are setup and what would the end result be. Please

Comment: Pls read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following tables:

```
CLASS
    id
    name
SUBJECT
   id
   name
CLASS_SUBJECT
   id
   class_id
   subject_id
WEEKLY_MARKS
   id
   class_subject_id
   test_date
   mark
```

The following query will work:

```
SELECT s.name as subject_name,
       c.name as class_name,
       wm.test_date,
       wm.mark
FROM   weekly_marks wm
INNER JOIN class_subject cs ON wm.class_subject_id = cs.id
INNER JOIN class c ON cs.class_id = c.id
INNER JOIN subject s ON cs.subject_id = s.id
```

A bit of a guess here, but assuming the class_subject table you're talking about is joining of subjects (students?) to the classes they are enrolled in.